# HDMI audio doesn't work through DisplayPort adapter on OS X but works on boot camped Win 7

Tags: audio, video-adapter, displayport, hdmi

I recently purchased this [Dynex DisplayPort to HDMI adapter](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/Dynex%26%23153%3B+-+Mini+DisplayPort-to-HDMI+Adapter/1025743.p?id=1218210319616&skuId=1025743) with the understanding that it would support audio out.

However, it only works on my boot camped Windows 7 install that way. Video and audio passed to the TV with no issues. On the other hand, I only get video passed when booted into OS X.

I have already tinkered with the sound configuration numerous times in an effort to get it to work. Googling turned up the fact that some adapters do not support passing audio through from the DisplayPort. I believe this is not the case since it works on Windows with no issues. I have also ensured that all updates have been installed. Still no dice.

Any ideas on how I can get the audio passed through to the TV?

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the option key and click on the volume icon in the menu bar. What does the menu say for Output Device? If your adapter doesn't appear, here's what you can do: Open /Applications/Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup. See if your adapter appears in the list to the left. If it does, play with the Configure Device and Configure Speakers options (accessed by the gear button).

Comment: I can see the device in both instances. I am able to play with the Configure Speakers and get static out of both speakers (when clicking on the button representing the speaker).

However, as soon as I switch to that device, the Volume icon in the menu bar grays out and no audio is played through any program...

Answer (score 1):

**It works!** As soon as you change your audio output to your TV, the audio should work.

Here is how to do it:

1. Hold down Option and click on the volume icon in the menu bar.
2. Change your audio output to the name of your TV. (i.e: XVA62619)
3. The audio icon will gray out, so don't worry about it.
4. Play something from your computer and it should work.

Comment: It doesn't. I tried this multiple times.

Comment: Not working here. I will assume the adapter does not support audio