# MacBook Pro HDMI No Sound

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hdmi

I purchased a MacBook Pro in March of 2011.  I plugged a mini-to-HDMI cable from my laptop into my Sony receiver.  I have no a picture, but no sound.

There is no external source listed in the sound options, only internal speakers.  I power cycled both my receiver and my laptop, but it didn't change anything.  I am running Lion and all of my software is up to date.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are lucky http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5738/hdmi-audio-doesnt-work-through-displayport-adapter-on-os-x-but-works-on-boot-ca might help

Comment: @George Are you sure the mini-DP to HDMI cable you have supports sound? Not all of them do.

Comment: I'm having your same problem, but even more strange, TV Samsung works sound, screen ASUS PA 246 is mute, using MBP and hdmi adapter

Comment: To eliminate the possibility that the receiver doesn't support audio over HDMI, could you try using another HDMI device like an Apple TV and let us know if you can hear the audio?